Verwendung von „rundweg“ in verschiedenen Stilen in Deutschland
Ich lerne schon ziemlich lange Deutsch und wohne zurzeit in Hannover. Kürzlich bin ich auf das Adverb „rundweg“ gestoßen, dessen Übersetzung einfach war, aber ich verstehe nicht wirklich, in welchen Sprachstilen es normalerweise verwendet wird. DWDS sagt uns, dass es umgangssprachlich sei (Duden nicht), aber sein Korpus der gesprochenen Sprache hat absolut keine Einträge mit diesem Wort, während der allgemeine Gegenwartskorpus 854 Einträge hat. Was denkt ihr, würdet ihr im Alltag so etwas wie „er hat es rundweg abgelehnt“ sagen oder ist es eher etwas, was einem in Büchern/formeller Rede begegnet?

Schon klar, googeln ist schwierig, weil sich allerlei Wander-Rundwege vordrängeln... Aber Stringsuche nach Kombinationen wie "rundweg gesagt" oder "rundweg abgelehnt" geht. Die zeigt glaub ich, dass das Wort in vielen Sprechstilen vorkommt. Zumindest in diesen Kombinationen.

@Alazon Danke, ja, habe ich schon gekuckt :) Ich dachte, vielleicht könnte ich aus der gesamten persönlichen Erfahrung anderer mehr lernen als aus einzelnen Webeinträgen, und habe mich deswegen hier erkundigt

Ich würde es nicht verwenden, weil es genügend gebräuchlichere Synonyme gibt. Besonders formell scheint es mir nicht, eher ein bisschen veraltet.

@Stefan Danke für die Meinung!

Nach Meinungen zu fragen, führt hier zum Schließen der Frage.

@Olafant Ich wüsste gerne, wie eine Frage, ob das Wort noch im Gebrauch ist, Tatsachen statt Meinungen voraussetzt

@aldin Siehe guidots Antwort.

Zur räumlichen Verwendung hat DWDS eine nette Karte, die in Richtung Südwesten weist, also bei Baden-Württemberg eine Spitze zeigt. Nach einem kurzen Überfliegen der Korpora bin ich von der Einstufung als umgangssprachlich nicht überzeugt, die aufgezeigten typischen Verbindungen wie verneinen, dementieren und bestreiten stützen das auch nicht.
Der Gebrauch des Wortes nimmt ab (siehe das DWDS-Diagramm), ist aber immer noch auf der Stufe von gutgläubig, das ich als gängig ansehe (es gibt dafür aber auch keine Alternative, die auf der Hand liegt).
Zusammenfassung: Wenn Dir das Wort gefällt, sehe ich keinen Grund, es nicht zu verwenden.
